# Google App Engine - JSONProperty vs Separate Model

Tags: google-app-engine

Say I have a blog app with blog posts and comments. Lets say for the sake of argument that there can be a very large number of comments, big enough that a simple `comments = StringProperty(repeated=True`) would be insufficient.

Should I store the comments as a JSONProperty (serialized from python list):

```
class BlogPost(ndb.Model):
  title = ndb.StringProperty()
  description = ndb.TextProperty()
  comments = ndb.JSONProperty()
```

Or should I create a separate Comment model altogether and store the corresponding blogpost's ID as a property:

```
class Comment(ndb.Model):
  text = ndb.TextProperty()
  blog_id = ndb.IntegerProperty()
  created = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
```

And I can query for all the comments of a specific blogpost as follows: `query = Comment.query(Comment.blog_id==blog_id).order(-Comment.created)`?

Is one approach preferable? Especially if comments could get very large > 1000.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You definitely want a separate model for comments.

One reason is that entities are limited to 1MB in size.  If one post gets a huge number of comments, then you are in danger of exceeding the limit and your code would crash.

Another reason is that you want to consider read/write rates for entities and scalability.  If you use JSON, then you need update the BlogPost entity every time a comment is made.  If a lot of people are writing comments at the same time, then you will need transactions and have contention issues.  If you have a separate model for comments, then you can easily scale to a million comments per second!

Comment: Thanks so much! In the Comment model, is it OK if I make the blog_id property a string? For some reason I was getting error in iOS with the long numeric iD. This won't make a difference right?

Comment: No, doesn't matter, but for the sake of simplicity I'd keep it an integer and fix whatever is going on in iOS.